# How would I eliminate spacing, line breaks to have a space-delimited string for each string within my list python

Tags: python, list, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Hi everyone I am pretty new to python and wanted some help. I have some sample data and wanted to know how would I get rid of spacing for each string within each list.

```
data = [
 ['In dolore     .'], ['Voluptatum.    '],
 ['Veniam hic non minima.         '],
 ['Dolores       Quis enim'], 
 ['     sequi ducimus']
 ]
 print data
```

The Output I desire:

```
data = [
 ['In dolore.'], ['Voluptatum.'],
 ['Veniam hic non minima.'],
 ['Dolores Quis enim'], 
 ['sequi ducimus']
 ]
```

Here are the two ways I thought would work but didn't

```
for i in data:
str = ''.join(data)
final_data = str.replace("  ","")
print final_data
```

my final attempt was this:

```
final_data = ''.join(data) 
final_data.replace("  ", "") 
print final_data
```

Comment: Is there a reason that `data` is a list of lists rather than just a list of strings?

Comment: What happened to the period for the `In dalore` and ['Voluptatum']  parts of your expected output? Why is it missing?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to keep the `.` in the third element but not in the two first ?

Comment: @yinnonsanders Great question.The reason data is a list of list is because I read them from a cvs file by using a for loop to read reach columns and appended each row to an empty list

Comment: @idjaw my apologies I forgot to add the period

Comment: @LoicM my apologies I forgot to add the period. I just made the correct edit for the output.

Comment: @mcd5185 No worries. There seem to be a couple of regex answers posted which give the correct output now. Good luck.

Comment: Also, do you mean csv file, not cvs?

Comment: @yinnonsanders you're correct I meant csv not cvs.

Comment: @mcd5185 You should consider accepting the answer that helped resolve your problem. It will also help further readers quickly see what answer was the most helpful in achieving your solution if they face the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex here

```
import re
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i][0] = re.sub(r'(\w)\s\s+(\w)', r'\1 \2', data[i][0])
    data[i][0] = re.sub(r'\s\s+', r'', data[i][0])
    data[i][0] = re.sub(r"(\w)\s([.])", r"\1\2", dat[i][0])
```

The regex pattern `\s\s+` matches all groups of 2 or more whitespace characters. As noted that would eliminate spacing between words if there was more than 1 space between two words. The `r'\w\s\s+\w', r'\1 \2'` takes care of that by eliminating the spaces between word boundaries with a single space.

Also note that it's `data[i][0]` because strangely the data is a list of lists.

Comment: This would eliminate all whitespace characters when there are >1 in a row, without leaving any between words. Also doesn't remove leading or trailing whitespaces.

Comment: This outputs `[['In dolore.'], ['Voluptatum.'], ['Veniam hic non minima.'], ['DoloresQuis enim'], ['sequi ducimus']]`. Which is not quite what the expected output should be. The regex needs to account for another case as well. Please edit. The upvotes are locked in until this answer is edited, and it is misleading to the final result.

Comment: @idjaw it's taken care of

Comment: Your provided code is raising a `invalid group reference`

Comment: @idjaw it's fixed by the way

Comment: Fails in the case of a string such as `"In dolore ."` with a single space before the period.

Comment: @yinnonsanders added something to take care of that

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
final_data = [[re.sub('\s+\.', '.', re.sub('\s+', ' ', s)).strip()] for l in data for s in l]
print final_data

[['In dolore.'], ['Voluptatum.'], ['Veniam hic non minima.'], ['Dolores Quis enim'], ['sequi ducimus']]
```

This way leading and trailing whitespaces are removed, while internal spaces are not eliminated entirely.

The inner substitution replaces multiple whitespace characters with a single spaces, and the outer substitution eliminates whitespace characters before a period. The `strip` function eliminates leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Not quite. You will still end up with `['In dolore .']` having a space between the last word and the period. The correct regex has already been posted.

Comment: Edited to remove all periods, because that seems like an acceptable option from the question.

Comment: The expected output preserves all periods. This wouldn't match the expected output if you remove all periods.

Comment: Provide the output that results from your code to show that it works. I ran it and it *is* in fact the expected output. The more you explain the better for a good complete answer.

Comment: Sorry, the answer wasn't clarified when I wrote that.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your original edit with the output, and I added mine. I took my edit out. :)

Answer (score 1):

`print [[s.replace("  ","")] for l in data for s in l ]`

Comment: `[' sequi ducimus']` and `['Veniam hic non minima. ']` still have extra spaces.

Comment: You can use the regex from Nick Chapman's answer or add put `s.replace("  ","").strip()`